# OpenSearch.Client sort by filtered nested documents

Tags: c#, .net, opensearch

I am trying to sort documents based on filtered nested documents, using the [OpenSearch.Client](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/OSC-dot-net/), exactly as in this question for `ElasticSearch`: [NEST elastic sort by filtered nested documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863624/nest-elastic-sort-by-filtered-nested-documents)

However, the options `OpenSearch.Client` provides appear different, and it appears that there is no option for filtering nested objects at all.

My sorting requirements are these:

```
    "sort": [
        {
            "copies.creationDate": {
                "order": "desc",
                "nested" : {
                    "path" : "copies",
                    "filter" : {
                        "term" : {"copies.idOwnedByGroup" : 1}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "idDocument": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
```

And I have tried this :

```
.Sort(sort => {
    return sort.Field(d => d.Copies.First().CreationDate, SortOrder.Descending).Field(d => d.IdDocument, SortOrder.Descending)
}
```

And this:

```
.Sort(sort => {
    return sort.Descending(d => d.Copies.First().CreationDate).Descending(d => d.IdDocument);
}
```

But those methods contain no option to specify any nested object filtering. And I see no other methods to use.

From OpenSearch Dashboards it is possible though, using the JSON query above.

Am I missing something? Maybe this is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this is similar to the NEST client, and I was just perplexed by the convoluted API:

```
Func<NestedSortDescriptor<Document>, INestedSort> nestedSortDescriptor = n => n
        .Path(copiesNestedPath)
        .Filter(sff => sff
            .Term(tq => tq.Field(copyIdOwnedByGroupPath).Value(request.IdOrgGroup)) // Actual filtering.
         );

return sort
   .Field(sf => sf
      .Field(d => d.Copies.First().CreationDate)
      .Order(SortOrder.Descending)
      .Nested(nestedSortDescriptor) // Required for fields inside nested objects.
    )
```

And then one could add the 2nd field as well.

**Important note:**
You might need to specify a VERY LARGE value (larger than the numer of indexed documents) with `.TrackTotalHits()` otherwise the sort seems to not return the expected results.

Comment: Can you please direct me to how you got this working as I am struggling to get it working and also trying 
{
  address:{
      addressLine1: "12 Bond street",
      postCode:"SL3 1BL"
  }                            
}

So basically I want to sort by "addressLine1" and possibly create a generic method

Comment: @Santosh If you use fields located inside nested objects for sorting (check your mapping to see if you use nested objects, but the default behavior is not to use nested objects), you can use the JSON in my question (look at the `copies.creationDate` portion). You will need to use the "nested" property and the "path" property that points to the path of the nested object (the parent object). If you are NOT using nested objects, you can simply sort by the field `addressLine1` the same way I do for `idDocument` in my question above. I have also updated my answer a bit. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks yes that definitely helps 